# How to clean up the following code into a if then function

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, toggle

Here is a noob question :-).

Is there a way to write the following code into a if then function so that it counts up without adding more entries?

```
<script>
$("#click1").click(function () {
$("#parentshowhide div:not(#show1)").hide();
$("#show1").show("fast");
});

$("#click2").click(function () {
$("#parentshowhide div:not(#show2)").hide();
$("#show2").show("fast");
});

$("#click3").click(function () {
$("#parentshowhide div:not(#show3)").hide();
$("#show3").show("fast");
});

$("#click4").click(function () {
$("#parentshowhide div:not(#show4)").hide();
$("#show4").show("slow");
});
</script>
```

Thanks in advance!!

---

Sorry to mislead you guys in the code.  The "fast" vs "slow" part of the code should be the same.  So either all fast or all slow, that does not need to be a variable.

I will test all the suggestions now.

Thanks,
Nathan

Answer (score 3):

If you see you're using `#click1`, `#click2`, `#click3`, etc. you should come to think that these items all have similar behaviour. There's a word for that in terms of markup, they all belong to the same *class*. So if you give `#clicki` the class `.button`, and workout the relative html structure, you can do that in one go:

```
$('.button').click(...)
```

Answer (score 2):

Indeed there is. It's all about finding the common things in code and making them reusable. Add to the config object as you need to. This solution will do exactly what you want but you will need to use the full power of selectors better by taking note of davin's answer.

```
var config = {
  1: 'fast',
  2: 'fast',
  3: 'fast',
  4: 'slow'
};

for (var key in config) {
  var value = config[key];

  $("#click" + key).click(function () {
    $("#parentshowhide div:not(#show" + key + ")").hide();
    $("#show" + key).show(value);
  });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Okay, here is the easiest way to do this I believe.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        // Add a class of 'toggle' to the links
        $("a.toggle").click(function(){
            // Create a variable to know which one we're hiding / showing
            var number = toInt($(this).attr("id").replace("click",""));
            $("#parentshowhide div:not(#show" + number)).hide();
            $("#show" + number).show("fast");
        })
    })
</script>
```

This is untested, but the logic is sound. Any issues please create a jsFiddle and I will follow it up.

Answer (score 0):

hm, I didn't test it but you could try the following:

```
<script>
var i=1;

while($("#click"+i)){
    $("#click"+i).click(function () {
        $("#parentshowhide div:not(#show"+i+")").hide();
        $("#show"+i).show("slow");
    }
    i++;
}

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you've got a tab set there. If `#click1` through `#clickX` all share the same parent, you could do something like this:

1. Make sure each of `#click1` - `#clickX` have some HTML property (like an `HREF`) that has the ID of the related element that should not get hidden. Then give all the `#click1` - `#clickX` a shared CSS class.
2. Bind, to the parent of the `#click` set, a function that (1) hides all the linked content by ID (using the `HREF` or other property); and then (2) shows the content identified by the clicked item.

Here's some JS (assuming `#click1` is an `A`, and that all `#clickX` are inside a `DIV` with ".tabset"):

```
$('a.clickable', $('.tabset')).live('click', function(event) {
   // hide all linked content
   var jThis = $(this);
   var jSet = jThis.closest('.tabset');
   jSet.find('a.clickable').each(function() {
      $('#' + $(arguments[1]).attr('href')).hide();
   });
   // show this one piece of content
   $('#' + jThis.attr('href')).show();

   // prevent further handling
   event.preventDefault();
   return false;

});
```

That code targets this markup:

```
<div class="tabset">
   <a class="clickable" href="#show1">View #1</a>
   <a class="clickable" href="#show2">View #2</a>
   ...
   <a class="clickable" href="#showX">View #X</a>
</div>

<div id="#show1"> [stuff here] </div>
<div id="#show2"> [more stuff] </div>
<div id="#showX"> [stufffffff] </div>
```

If you can't (or don't want to) have all the #clickX items in a single container, some minor changes would need to be made. You'd need to collect all the items into a collection that could be accessed during the click handler, so all the "rival" content could still be identified and hidden.